# Struct found nil while unwrapping

Tags: swift, struct, option-type

I have a struct named `AwardData` with 3 fields, a `title : String`, a `description : String`, and `completed : Bool`. I'm trying to create an instance of one of these then set its data like this:

```
var data : AwardData!

        switch awardNum
        {
        case 0:
            data.title = "Roomie"
```

However I'm running into an error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Is how I'm making the instance of the struct incorrect?

Comment: You don't make an instance at all, you're only declaring `data` as implicit unwrapped optional, which is `nil`.

Comment: Implicitly unwrapped optionals strike again. I wonder why everyone suggests to avoid them. /s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var data: AwardData!` declares an implicitly-unwrapped `Optional` variable. It's almost as if you wrote `var data: AwardData?`. The `!` at the end makes it implicitly unwrapped, which basically just means that the compiler won't complain about you using it like a normal (non-optional) variable.

The real problem is that you haven't initialized your `data` variable yet. You only declared its type, but didn't create the actual structure. It's nil, but you try to assign a value to its `title`.

You could do this instead:

```
var data = AwardData()
```

And then set the title without problems:

```
data.title = "Roomie"
```